# ASP.NET Core 1.1 (Dynamic Controller Loading)

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I've done this before with WCF (using VirtualPathProvider), and again later with WebAPI2 (using DefaultHttpControllerSelector), to implement a plugin system for enterprise web applications that supports live updating. so I'm hoping their is a way to do this in ASP.NET Core 1.1, but I just haven't found the appropriate process yet.

What I would like to achieve is the following basic scenario. If an request fails to match an existing controller route, use the controller name provided by the request to probe a folder for a matching controller assembly. If a match is found load the assembly into the domain, and continue to process the request, otherwise just return a 404.

So far all my research has come up empty handed... but I'm completely new to .NET Core so there is still a lot I have to learn. While I continue my research, if anyone can provide any insight, I would greatly appreciate it.